# Table with combination of multirows and multicolumns

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I need to create similar table using LaTeX:

[image]

I have tried to use `\tabular` and `\multicolumn`, but every time I get something wrong.

Could someone help me?

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | }
 \hline
\  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \    & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
\  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \     & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
 &  & No 0 &  &  &  &  & No  1 &  &  &  &  & No  2 &  &  &  &  & No 3 &  &  &  &      \\ \hline
      &  & TT & FF & P & R & F & TT & FF & P & R & F & TT & FF & P & R & F & TP & FP & P & R & F \\ \hline


     A & A1 & 2 & 3 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 3 & 7 & 0.3 & 0.6 & 0.54 & 5 & 12 & 0.28 & 1 & 0.79 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
      & A2 & 1 & 12 & 0.08 & 0.5 & 0.31 & 2 & 14 & 0.13 & 1 & 0.56 & 2 & 4 & 0.33 & 1 & 0.82 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
      & A3 & 0 & 0 & na & na & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & na & 0 & 0 & 0 & na & na & na & 0 & 0 & na & na & na \\ \hline

     B & B1 & 2 & 9 & 0.18 & 0.5 & 0.42 & 3 & 26 & 0.12 & 0.75 & 0.47 & 4 & 30 & 0.12 & 1 & 0.54 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
     & B2 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 3 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 0.45 & 2 & 2 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.9 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
     & B3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 3 & 0.25 & 1 & 0.75 & 1 & 2 & 0.33 & 1 & 0.82 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline

      C & C1 & 1 & 56 & 0.02 & 1 & 0.14 & 1 & 38 & 0.03 & 1 & 0.19 & 1 & 11 & 0.08 & 1 & 0.45 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    & C2 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 1 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.9 & 1 & 1 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.9 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    & C3 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & na & 0 & 7 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 4 & 0.2 & 1 & 0.69 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline

      D & D1 & 0 & 37 & 0 & 0 & na & 2 & 16 & 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.27 & 3 & 18 & 0.14 & 0.5 & 0.39 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0.53 \\ \hline
   & D2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & na & 3 & 2 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.49 & 4 & 2 & 0.67 & 1 & 0.95 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    & D3 & 0 & 0 & na & na & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & na & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & na & na & 0 & 0  & na & na & na \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This takes inspiration from an [answer given by Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172662/39222) using `makecell`. I used this because it seems that the use of vertical rules is essential to the look desired for this question and that excludes use of `booktabs`. Like `booktabs`, `makecell` adds some extra spacing to LaTeX's rather squashed default tabular layout, and supports the use of variable width rules.

***Caveat emptor...*** The code may suffer from the fact that I've never used this package before.

The tabular will not fit horizontally without reducing its size (whatever package is used) so it is typeset in landscape orientation instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \noindent\begin{tabular}{ !{\vrule width1.2pt}c!{\vrule width1.2pt}c!{\vrule width1.2pt}*{5}{c}!{\vrule width1.2pt}*{5}{c}!{\vrule width1.2pt}*{5}{c}!{\vrule width1.2pt}*{5}{c}!{\vrule width1.2pt} }
 \Xcline{3-22}{1.2pt}
   \multicolumn{2}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{}  & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{\thead{No 0}}  & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{\thead{No 1}}  & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{\thead{No 2}}  & \multicolumn{5}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{\thead{No 3}}     \\\Xcline{3-22}{1.2pt}
   \multicolumn{2}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{}  & \thead{TT} & \thead{FF} & \thead{P} & \thead{R} & \thead{F} & \thead{TT} & \thead{FF} & \thead{P} & \thead{R} & \thead{F} & \thead{TT} & \thead{FF} & \thead{P} & \thead{R} & \thead{F} & \thead{TP} & \thead{FP} & \thead{P} & \thead{R} & \thead{F} \\\Xhline{1.2pt}
     \multirowthead{3}{A} & \thead{A1} & 2 & 3 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 3 & 7 & 0.3 & 0.6 & 0.54 & 5 & 12 & 0.28 & 1 & 0.79 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
      & \thead{A2} & 1 & 12 & 0.08 & 0.5 & 0.31 & 2 & 14 & 0.13 & 1 & 0.56 & 2 & 4 & 0.33 & 1 & 0.82 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
      & \thead{A3} & 0 & 0 & na & na & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & na & 0 & 0 & 0 & na & na & na & 0 & 0 & na & na & na \\\Xhline{1.2pt}
     \multirowthead{3}{B} & \thead{B1} & 2 & 9 & 0.18 & 0.5 & 0.42 & 3 & 26 & 0.12 & 0.75 & 0.47 & 4 & 30 & 0.12 & 1 & 0.54 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
     & \thead{B2} & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 3 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 0.45 & 2 & 2 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.9 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
     & \thead{B3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 3 & 0.25 & 1 & 0.75 & 1 & 2 & 0.33 & 1 & 0.82 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xhline{1.2pt}
    \multirowthead{3}{C} & \thead{C1} & 1 & 56 & 0.02 & 1 & 0.14 & 1 & 38 & 0.03 & 1 & 0.19 & 1 & 11 & 0.08 & 1 & 0.45 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
    & \thead{C2} & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 1 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.9 & 1 & 1 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.9 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
    & \thead{C3} & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & na & 0 & 7 & 0 & 0 & na & 1 & 4 & 0.2 & 1 & 0.69 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xhline{1.2pt}
   \multirowthead{3}{D}& \thead{D1} & 0 & 37 & 0 & 0 & na & 2 & 16 & 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.27 & 3 & 18 & 0.14 & 0.5 & 0.39 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0.53 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
   & \thead{D2} & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & na & 3 & 2 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.49 & 4 & 2 & 0.67 & 1 & 0.95 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\Xcline{2-2}{1.2pt}
    & \thead{D3} & 0 & 0 & na & na & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & na & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & na & na & 0 & 0  & na & na & na \\\Xhline{1.2pt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular in landscape orientation]

Answer (score 1):

Here again (and offering an alternative to @cfr 's solution —and also copying part of it :P—). With `tap`. Far from okay, but `tap` offers some flexibility.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\input{tap}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\deftable\tmptable
\begintable
    \begintableformat
        & \center
    \endtableformat
    \B"- @2                       ! @20 \=                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \E!
    \B": @2                       ! @5 \textbf{No 1}                                       ! @5 \textbf{No 2}                                       ! @5 \textbf{No 3}                                       ! @5 \textbf{No 4}                                       \E!
    \B"- @2                       ! @20 \=                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \E!
    \B": @2                       ! \emph{TT} " \emph{FF} " \emph{P} " \emph{R} " \emph{F} ! \emph{TT} " \emph{FF} " \emph{P} " \emph{R} " \emph{F} ! \emph{TT} " \emph{FF} " \emph{P} " \emph{R} " \emph{F} ! \emph{TT} " \emph{FF} " \emph{P} " \emph{R} " \emph{F} \E!
    \=
    \B!: \textbf{A} ! \textbf{A1} ! 2         " 3         " 0.4      " 0.4      " 0.4      ! 3         " 7         " 0.3      " 0.6      " 0.54     ! 5         " 12        " 0.28     " 1        " 0.79     ! 5         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{A2} ! 1         " 12        " 0.08     " 0.5      " 0.31     ! 2         " 14        " 0.13     " 1        " 0.56     ! 2         " 4         " 0.33     " 1        " 0.82     ! 2         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{A3} ! 0         " 0         " na       " na       " 0        ! 0         " 4         " 0        " na       " 0        ! 0         " 0         " na       " na       " na       ! 0         " 0         " na       " na       " na       \E!
    \=
    \B!: \textbf{B} ! \textbf{B1} ! 2         " 9         " 0.18     " 0.5      " 0.42     ! 3         " 26        " 0.12     " 0.75     " 0.47     ! 4         " 30        " 0.12     " 1        " 0.54     ! 4         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{B2} ! 0         " 3         " 0        " 0        " na       ! 1         " 3         " 0.25     " 0.5      " 0.45     ! 2         " 2         " 0.5      " 1        " 0.9      ! 2         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{B3} ! 0         " 1         " 0        " 0        " na       ! 1         " 3         " 0.25     " 1        " 0.75     ! 1         " 2         " 0.33     " 1        " 0.82     ! 1         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \=
    \B!: \textbf{C} ! \textbf{C1} ! 1         " 56        " 0.02     " 1        " 0.14     ! 1         " 38        " 0.03     " 1        " 0.19     ! 1         " 11        " 0.08     " 1        " 0.45     ! 1         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{C2} ! 0         " 8         " 0        " 0        " na       ! 1         " 1         " 0.5      " 1        " 0.9      ! 1         " 1         " 0.5      " 1        " 0.9      ! 1         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{C3} ! 0         " 2         " 0        " 0        " na       ! 0         " 7         " 0        " 0        " na       ! 1         " 4         " 0.2      " 1        " 0.69     ! 1         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \=
    \B!: \textbf{D} ! \textbf{D1} ! 0         " 37        " 0        " 0        " na       ! 2         " 16        " 0.11     " 0.33     " 0.27     ! 3         " 18        " 0.14     " 0.5      " 0.39     ! 3         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 0.53     \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{D2} ! 0         " 2         " 0        " 0        " na       ! 3         " 2         " 0.4      " 0.5      " 0.49     ! 4         " 2         " 0.67     " 1        " 0.95     ! 4         " 0         " 1        " 1        " 1        \E!
    \B!-            ! \=          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          !           "           "          "          "          \E!
    \B!:            ! \textbf{D3} ! 0         " 0         " na       " na       " 0        ! 0         " 6         " 0        " na       " 0        ! 0         " 1         " 0        " na       " na       ! 0         " 0         " na       " na       " na       \E!
    \=
\endtable

\begin{landscape}
    \mbox{\begintable\tmptable\endtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```